# Reference request: Tiling the plane with congruent snowflakes

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, formal-languages, symmetry, tiling

A straightforward approach for finding tilings of congruent, six-fold symmetrical tiles is to use a wallpaper-symmetrical tiling (I haven’t found any tilings that don’t have p6 or p6m symmetry). A trivial solution is to tile the plane with hexagons; if the symmetry axis of the tile *doesn’t* line up with the translation of the tiling, the solutions are more complex.

I have made a JS applet for drawing and generating these tilings, the page
also has some example images https://istscilveks.itch.io/snowflake-tilings

[image: Example snowflake tiling with jigsaw-like edges]

It seems like all the snowflakes are either made of smaller hexagons or are fractals, depending on the angle. I suspect that the boundary can be described using a formal language, as has been done with *double square* polyomino tiles (*"polyominoes yielding two distinct periodic tilings by translated copies such that every polyomino in the tiling is surrounded by exactly four copies"*) in [Combinatorial properties of double square tiles](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/77618582.pdf). In fig. 11 some of the tiles are solutions to a related problem: tiling the plane with congruent, *four*-fold symmetrical tiles.

**That paper and others on polyomino tilings, plus a few disparate solutions, are about all that I could find, so I would like to know if anyone has any resources or has heard of a problem like this.**

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any discussion of this problem online, so I went ahead myself and made an algorithm which can exhaustively generate the figures described, given a few extra assumptions. **[The linked paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/77618582.pdf) turned out to be exactly what was needed to solve the problem**, and here I give some of the steps for my modified algorithm (I haven't written the full algorithm in English). I defined a snowflake as a figure that has has all the symmetries of a regular hexagon, and a tileable snowflake as a snowflake for which the following assumptions also hold:

- The figure is a polygon with a finite number of edges where all edges are of equal length and all angles are equal or explementary (i.e. summing to $2π$). This means that the tileable snowflakes must be polyhexes.
- The figure admits a tiling which is topologically equivalent to the hexagonal tiling in which the center of each snowflake and each vertex of the tiling is a center of symmetry of orders $6$ and $3$ respectively.

[image: A simple example of a tilable snowflake is shown on a hexagonal grid. Each edge of its boundary has a number corresponding to the absolute direction of the path around the boundary]

The assumptions allow the boundary of each tileable snowflake to be described using a combinatorial word: a list of digits that increase or decrease by one (modulo $6$), where each digit represents a unit step in a certain direction.

[image: The effect of each operator on one tileable snowflake is shown. The inverses are also shown, i.e., for each operator there is another operator that undoes the change.]

I also modified the operators from the paper and proved that:

- operators turn one tileable snowflake into another (under mild conditions);
- each operator is reversible (under mild conditions);
- for each tileable snowflake (except the regular hexagon) there exists an operator that gives a tileable snowflake with fewer edges.

Then, by Fermat’s infinite descent principle, these operators are sufficient to generate any tileable snowflake that conforms to my assumptions.

Additionally, I generalized the proof to other tilings: for any $p,q>3$, a snowflake is a figure with all the symmetries of a regular $p$-gon and a tileable snowflake admits a tiling that is topologically equivalent to the tiling with Schläfli symbol $\{p, q\}$. The center of each snowflake and each vertex of the tiling is assumed to be a center of symmetry of orders $p$ and $q$ respectively.

I also improved [the app](https://istscilveks.itch.io/snowflake-tilings) to allow generating snowflakes by inputting a string of operators.